# preg_match condition when the block will execute?

Tags: php, pcre

`preg_match` condition when the block will execute?

I have an

```
$A = Array (
 [0] => KSO/OCMT/GBP66401,/ 001 VTS EMIS 43628
 [1] => KSO/OCMT/GBP1836,22/ ENCT LCR 090724 
)   

$test = 'KSO';

foreach($A as $temp_indice=>$temp)
{
      if(preg_match("`(.*)".$test."(.*)`im", $temp,$matches)) 
       {
        //WHEN THIS BLOCK IS EXECUTE?
       }
    }
```

I have read [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) not get the understand from the above code.

Could anybody here good understand about `preg_match` explain me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

preg_match() is about regular expressions (aka regex), its goal is to search if a string matches a specific pattern, for example check if it contains a specific word, if it's an email, a zip code, ...

Here your regex will match any string containing the string 'KSO'. Regex uses a specific syntax, that's probably why you don't understand how it works. You will find more details here : http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @stackunderflow : `im` are regex's options. `i` for ignoreCase, `m` for multiline (which may be useless here).

Comment: Thanks LadaRaider for your guide .@Shikiryu for more clear.have a nice days

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match` returns `0` if no match is found and `1` if there's a match (and stop there, use `preg_match_all` for more)

`0` is also known as the boolean `false` and `1` for `true`.

That means, **if a match is found (each time `KSO` found in a row of your array named `$A`) it'll execute the block**